# Gensim: How to load corpus from saved lda model?

Tags: gensim, lda, corpus

When I saved my LdaModel `lda_model.save('model')`, it saved 4 files:

1. `model`
2. `model.expElogbeta.npy`
3. `model.id2word`
4. `model.state`

I want to use `pyLDAvis.gensim` to visualize the topics, which seems to need the model, corpus and dictionary. I was able to load the model and dictionary with:

```
lda_model = LdaModel.load('model')
dict = corpora.Dictionary.load('model.id2word')
```

Is it possible to load the corpus? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing this here because it took me awhile to find out the answer to this as well. Note that `dict` is not a valid name for a dictionary and we use `lda_dict` instead.

```
# text array is a list of lists containing text you are analysing
# eg. text_array = [['volume', 'eventually', 'metric', 'rally'], ...]
# lda_dict is a gensim.corpora.Dictionary object

bow_corpus = [lda_dict.doc2bow(doc) for doc in text_array]
```

Answer (score 1):

Jireh answered correctly but it may be confusing how to load all the previous LDA files.  I'm not sure why gensim saves the *.state and *.npy files (I'd appreciate insights in the comments).  To reuse a previous LDA model you load the *.model and *.id2word files along with your original corpus.

For instance, if I have a dataframe of my documents in column 'docs' then you load that dataframe again as you will need it to recreate your corpus.

```
import pandas as pd
from gensim import corpora, models
from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary
from pyLDAvis import gensim_models

df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')
texts = df['docs'].values
```

You load your previously created dictionary as follows:

```
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary.load('your_file.id2word')
```

... and then create the corpus from the dictionary and your original texts (created from the dataframe['docs'] above):

```
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]
```

The previously created LDA model is loaded via gensim:

```
lda_model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel.load('your_file.model')
```

These objects are then fed into your pyLDAvis instance:

```
lda_viz = pyLDAvis.gensim_models.prepare(lda_model, corpus, dictionary)
```

If you don't use the .id2word file you can run into issues with not having the correct shape (IndexError).  I've had this happen when I ran LDA multicore so I use the .id2word rather than recreating the dictionary from the corpus.

Answer (score 0):

in the gensim python code, they said ignore expElogbeta and state file. It is possible to load the corpus, corpus is a set of list contain 2 numbers. It will be complex to load it out, I suggest load corpus from the origin text data and using id2word